# iTunes links -- reliably determine what the link points to (apps, music, etc.)

Tags: ios, itunes

I am writing an iOS app and trying to substitute the right app in my links so they will work without a stutter step.  A few examples may help illustrate the problem:

The following are app links.  The "http" needs to be replaced with "itms-apps" or there will be a stutter step.

```
http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?id=25204&popId=30&genreId=36&partnerId=30&siteID=sf2bW7QX_qU-PYkdOXLGQzH9tPJ7y1QAuw
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anagramania/id360016055?mt=8&uo=4&partnerId=30&partnerId=30&siteID=sf2bW7QX_qU-AwzkWKpCWyE0dwCjsGbGtQ
```

The following are music links.  The "http" needs to be replaced with "itms" or there will be a stutter step.

```
http://itunes.apple.com/?partnerId=30&id=sf2bW7QX/qU
http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/music/?partnerId=30&siteID=sf2bW7QX_qU-x1LxUWfax2clPuyktSJuhg
http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?id=1&popId=11&genreId=34&partnerId=30&siteID=sf2bW7QX_qU-Vxd9s9XSv5efA24dZHd.TA
```